# Add a line to each facet in a grid

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet, facet-grid

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
  dates          types vals
1 2018-02-01     a     10
2 2018-03-01     a     11
3 2018-04-01     a     12
4 2018-05-01     b     20
5 2018-06-01     b     21
6 2018-07-01     b     22
7 2018-08-01     c     30
8 2018-09-01     c     31
9 2018-10-01     c     32
```

I've visualized it as a grid with 3 facets (one for each type: a, b, and c), with a common X-axis (the dates):

```
gg <- ggplot(df, aes(x = dates, y = vals)) + 
  geom_line(aes(color = df$types)) +
  geom_point() +
  facet_grid(types ~ ., scales = "free_y") +
  scale_color_manual(values =c("blue", "orange", "green"))
```

[image]

Now I'd like to add a horizontal line for each facet, such that each facet will have its own y-intercept. Based on similar questions, I've tried to create a dataframe with a column of intercepts:

```
lower = seq(10,30,10); upper = seq(12,32,10)
bounds <- data.frame(lower, upper)
```

And add it using `geom_hline`:

```
gg + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = lower), data = bounds, color = 'red')
```

But the result is having each facet all three lines, instead of its own row (I also want to add a line with the `upper` column, but I guess the solution is symmetric).

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add the `lower` specification to match the faceted data like so:

```
library('dplyr')
df <- df %>% mutate(lower = rep(c(10,20,30), each =3))
df
       dates types vals lower
1 2018-02-01     a   10    10
2 2018-03-01     a   11    10
3 2018-04-01     a   12    10
4 2018-05-01     b   20    20
5 2018-06-01     b   21    20
6 2018-07-01     b   22    20
7 2018-08-01     c   30    30
8 2018-09-01     c   31    30
9 2018-10-01     c   32    30
```

Then specify the plot as before and add the `geom_hline` like so on the altered df with `lower` column - like so:

```
gg + geom_hline(aes(yintercept = lower), color = 'red')
```

Then you get something like this:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! This works, but is there a way to load `lower` from a separate dataframe?

Comment: Not simply I don't think - perhaps someone else has a solution? Because the context that ggplot is using is in the `types` column. It's not clever enough to recognise the new data should be faceted too but it is automatic if the data is together in the original `gg`.

Comment: I see, what a pity I can't keep things tidy ;-)

Comment: `tidy` has a specific meaning for `R`. And this solution is `tidy` as it keeps the data together in a single one row one case format. Data split over multiple objects and maybe different lengths re your original code is what we call `untidy` hereabouts.

Answer (score 1):

Though there is an [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733973/add-a-line-to-each-facet-in-a-grid/56734317#56734317), here is one way of [loading `bounds` from another dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56733973/add-a-line-to-each-facet-in-a-grid/56734317#comment100027730_56734317), like the OP asks for in a comment.

First, see where the `types` should go in dataframe `bounds`.

```
cbind(bounds, types = c('a', 'b', 'c'))
#  lower upper types
#1    10    12     a
#2    20    22     b
#3    30    32     c
```

And what the result is when merged with the original `df`.

```
merge(cbind(bounds, types = c('a', 'b', 'c')), df)
#  types lower upper      dates vals
#1     a    10    12 2018-02-01   10
#2     a    10    12 2018-03-01   11
#3     a    10    12 2018-04-01   12
#4     b    20    22 2018-05-01   20
#5     b    20    22 2018-06-01   21
#6     b    20    22 2018-07-01   22
#7     c    30    32 2018-08-01   30
#8     c    30    32 2018-09-01   31
#9     c    30    32 2018-10-01   32
```

Seems right, just where the `types` need to be.
So plot it, adapting the code in the question.

```
gg + geom_hline(data = merge(cbind(bounds, types = c('a', 'b', 'c')), df),
             aes(yintercept = lower), 
             color = 'red')
```

[image]